# Windows 10 with 4GB RAM (HDD) optimization setup for MERN stack development

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, windows-10, mean-stack, mern

I'm developing with MONGODB service & Express server running and React app compiling on my Windows 10 with 4GB RAM *(HDD)*.

These are my optimization setups to improve my hardware performance, I guess some of them are now automatically revised by Windows itself.

- My virtualization is enabled.
- Most tips on https://youtu.be/nVy4GAtkh7Q including to Disable Privacy Settings, High Performance Power Settings and to Disable Indexing, excluding to Disable Firewall and the execution of any program.
- I have used: https://github.com/10se1ucgo/DisableWinTracking
- I'm now using Opera since it's more lighter than Chrome.
- I'm disabling Windows Defender while my local servers are running.

Setups that I'm not preferred to use:

- Not preferred to use Chrome 'cause my React app's tab is sometimes freezing.
- Not to debloat Windows with https://github.com/W4RH4WK/Debloat-Windows-10 since it have a possibility to mess up something.
- Not to permanently deactivate Windows Defender.
- Not to disable Opera hardware acceleration 'cause the 3D graphics without acceleration is like in slow mo.

Current issues:

- Opera is sometimes crashing *(still better than freezing)*.
- VS Code still experiencing lag.

Is there anything that I can do to improve the performance of my 4GB *(HDD)* hardware *(while I'm in short to buy a powerful hardware)*? Is there a recommended setup for MERN stack development?

Comment: If your machine came with 4GB of ram as standard it probably has a potato CPU which will also be causing issues. Your best bet would to be to uninstall windows and use some Linux distro that is optimised for low spec machines. You will probably get more out your machine if you go down that route and experience less hangups. Install ones of these https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/best-lightweight-linux-distro

Comment: What do you mean by "4GB (*HDD*)"? Wouldn't it be easier to just buy more RAM? It's pretty cheap. In any case, 4GB, while not much, should still allow you to run VS Code and a browser (even Chrome), if somewhat slowly. Bear in mind that VS Code is an Electron app, so you're running Chrome anyway, and it's not the fastest/lightest-weight text editor out there. Either way, SO isn't the place to ask.

Comment: @DaveNewton I mean 4GB RAM with hard disk drive.

Comment: I think having some form of mass storage is generally assumed.

Comment: @DaveNewton What do you mean about that, could you give an example? I guess, VS Code's file explorer is also bugging my hardware and needed to be replaced by some other lightweight. Any recommended developer lightweight editor? Is it VIM or else?

Comment: Example of what? System slowness is essentially impossible to diagnose or debug remotely without direct access (even if SO *was* the place to ask about it, which it isn't). FWIW, I've run VS Code (and Chrome) on 4GB Win10 laptops, although 8GB is pretty much my lower limit for a development machine. Linux will (generally) be a more-performant solution. But again: SO isn't the place to ask about system performance.